# Python fails on valid CP437 character

Tags: python, file, io, codepages

The downwards arrow (`↓`) is a valid character in the [CP437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) encoding. I'm writing a program which needs to read and write files with this encoding, but when I try to write a string containing this character to a file, I recieve the following error:

```py
File "C:\Python34\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 19, in encode
   return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2193' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
```

The same thing happens for other CP437 characters, such as `↔`.
My code is below, in case I've done something stupid there...

```py
ENCODING = 'CP437'

def writeFile(name, text):
    f = open(name, 'w', encoding = ENCODING)
    f.write(text)
    f.close()
```

According to Wikipedia, it's valid in the specified encoding, so why does python tell me otherwise? How can I fix this?

Comment: "Wikipedia says it's valid" - what is valid for what? Does Python actively aupport CP437?

Comment: @RadLexus I meant that apparently it's valid in CP437. And, python has a  `cp437.py` in the library, so it should be supported.

Comment: what version are you using? python 3.5.1 has a lot of unicode deprecations

Comment: @rassar currently on 3.4.3

Comment: If you look at the citation on that Wikipedia table, it points to [this Unicode consortium table](http://www.unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/MICSFT/PC/CP437.TXT), which has those positions in CP437 being mapped to control characters like "CANCEL" and "END OF TRANSMISSION" rather than visual arrows.  It's unclear why the table in the article shows the arrow characters but cites a table that doesn't support that interpretation.

Comment: @BrenBarn ah, i see. thanks for spotting that.

Comment: Poking around I found a link to [an old revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Code_page_437&direction=next&oldid=608954202) of the Wikipedia page that has more information about differing interpretations of the characters in that range.

Comment: How are you expecting the arrow glyphs to be serialised in the output file from your program? For instance, how many bytes will represent the up arrow and what will they be?

Comment: I meant my question seriously.

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46942721/is-cp437-decoding-broken-for-control-characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Wiki page that you've linked to says (just above the table that shows the down arrow as `0x19`):

> Although the ROM provides a graphic for all 256 different possible 8-bit codes, some APIs will not print some code points, in particular the range 1-31 and the code at 127. Instead they will interpret them as control characters. For instance many methods of outputting text on the original IBM PC would interpret the codes for BEL, BS, CR and LF. Many printers were also unable to print these characters.

The character you're trying to encode, the down-arrow, is the same character as the ASCII control character `EM` (End of Medium). What it would mean in an old program would depend on context. In Python, the characters mentioned in the quote above (1-31 and 127) are always interpreted as control characters, rather than as printable characters.

Comment: +1, but you're missing the code for printing the character which Python interprets as a control character and which some legacy systems will interpret as the down arrow.

Answer (score 0):

A mystery to me but does this do what you need?

```
f = open('somethin.txt', 'wb')
s1 = ( chr(8595)+chr(8593)+chr(8592)+chr(8594) ) . encode ( 'utf-8' )
s2 = '↓↑←→' . encode ( 'utf-8' )
f.write( s1 )
f.write( s2 )
f.close()
```

**s1** and **s2** are identical byte strings.

Comment: not really, because I needed to write the files with the CP437 encoding, but thanks for the reply anyway.