# Is CP437 decoding broken for control characters?

Tags: python, character-encoding

According to the [Wikipedia page for Code Page 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) the byte values `\x01` through `\x1f` should decode to graphic characters, e.g. `b'\x01'` equates to ☺ `'\u263A'`. But that's not what `decode` produces:

```
>>> b'\x01'.decode('cp437')
'\x01'
```

That was Python 3.6 but 2.7 does the same, for all 31 byte values.

Comment: The translation table provided by unicode seems to disagree with wikipedia: ftp://www.unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/MICSFT/PC/CP437.TXT

Answer (score 4):

While there were graphics associated with the byte range `\x01` through `\x1f`, those graphics were only used in some contexts. In other contexts, those code points would be interpreted as control characters, as in ASCII. Quoting an [IBM page on CP437](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/globalization/cp/cp00437.html):

> Code points X'01' through X'1F' and X'7F' may be controls or graphics depending on context. For displays the hexadecimal code in a memory-mapped 
>   video display buffer is a graphic. For printers the graphics context is established by a preceding control sequence in the data stream. There are two 
>   such control sequences: ESC X'5C' and ESC X'5E' named Print All Characters and Print Single Character respectively. In other situations the code 
>   points in question are used as controls.

Python's CP437 decoding is based on the [Unicode mappings on Unicode.org](ftp://www.unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/MICSFT/PC/CP437.TXT), which use the control character interpretation.

The [Unicode FAQ implies](http://unicode.org/faq/char_combmark.html#5) that "The correct Unicode mappings for the special graphic characters (01-1F, 7F) of CP437 and other DOS-type code pages" should be available at https://www.unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS, but digging down there only turns up the mappings with the control characters, and a [page](http://www.unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/IBM/IBM_conversions.html) linking to several IBM websites. Digging through IBM's sites turns up ftp://ftp.software.ibm.com/software/globalization/gcoc/attachments/CP00437.txt, which gives graphical mappings for `\x01`-`\x1f` in terms of IBM's [GCGID system](https://www-01.ibm.com/software/globalization/gcgid/gcgid.html), but not in terms of Unicode.

I don't know if there actually *is* an official mapping, from either IBM or Unicode, that gives canonical Unicode mappings for `\x01`-`\x1f` in terms of the graphical interpretation of CP437.

Comment: Thats what I thought, didn't find a reference yet though. Windows codepages are weird..

Comment: Fantastic reference, thanks. Is there any way to get those graphics characters other than making your own conversion table?

Comment: @MarkRansom: The closest I've found is [IBM's table](ftp://ftp.software.ibm.com/software/globalization/gcoc/attachments/CP00437.txt), which gives CP437 mappings in terms of IBM's GCGID system, but not in terms of Unicode.

Comment: FYI, "some contexts" includes **the Windows CMD**! Try it yourself: `python -c "import sys;print('\u263a\u263b');sys.stdout.buffer.write(b'\x01\x02\n')"`

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find this file in there:
https://unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/MISC/IBMGRAPH.TXT

It includes a mapping of the Unicode characters (0x01-0x1f) to IBM CP437, as well as IBM CP864 (Arabic).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's broken.

As far as I know, there is not **any system in existence today** that actually corresponds with the PSF's "cp437" encoding.

That encoding was copied from [this weird table by a Microsoft delegate to the Unicode Consortium](http://unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/MICSFT/PC/CP437.TXT); it disagrees with IBM on codepoints 0x01–0x1f (inclusive), and also **disagrees with Windows** over the same range, excepting *only* these characters, which it at least gets correct:

- `b'\x07'` emits a [Bell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_character) on the Windows CMD, but a Bullet on IBM memory-mapped graphics
- `b'\x08'` emits a Backspace on the Windows CMD, but an Inverted Bullet on IBM memory-mapped graphics
- `b'\x09'` emits a Horizontal Tab on the Windows CMD, but a White Circle on IBM memory-mapped graphics
- `b'\x0a'` emits a Carriage Return on the Windows CMD, but an Inverse White Circle on IBM memory-mapped graphics
- `b'\x0d'` emits a Line Feed on the Windows CMD, but a Music Note / Eigth Note on IBM memory-mapped graphics

As the other answer notes, the Unicode Consortium [did produce](https://unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/MISC/IBMGRAPH.TXT) a table documenting the behavior of IBM memory-mapped graphics — though they [never did produce](https://unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/MICSFT/) any table documenting the behavior of the Windows CMD.

Python did *not* include even the IBM graphical table, though, instead [aliasing "ibm437" to the weird ASCII-chimera](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.12.2/Lib/encodings/aliases.py#L126) Unicode erroneously recorded as CP437.

No, no-one's filed this as a bug with the PSF yet. Probably no-one will, because of 2 reasons:

First, `b'\x1b'` emits a Left Arrow on the Windows CMD, but libraries like [colorama](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama) are hard-coded to interpret that byte as an Escape character, and finding a resolution to that will be a nuisance requiring a lot of co-ordination and causing a lot of collateral breakage.

Second, codepage 437 is virtually never *actually* used these days, since CPython 3.6 added an [invisible UTF-16 console I/O under-the-hood on Windows](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.0/Modules/_io/winconsoleio.c#L959).

---

If you want to use codepage `x-microsoft-437` for your own purposes (for example, writing out text files that will render correctly when used with [`type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/type), or doing Unicode I/O on PyPy on Windows), here's a conservative snippet  you could add to your own code:

```
"""https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46942721

Registers codecs x-microsoft-437 and x-ibm-graphical.
"""

# -*- filename: _site_codecs/x_microsoft_437.py -*-

# Remember that sys.stdin.reconfigure() cannot be called after any input has been read
# So if you're using this for I/O, please call that ONLY in __main__ after appropriate checks
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77808931

import codecs
import encodings
from encodings import cp437 as _psf_cp437


def _cp437_search_function(encoding):
    if encodings.normalize_encoding(encoding) == encodings.normalize_encoding(_Cp437CodecInfo.name):
        return _Cp437CodecInfo
    return None

codecs.register(_cp437_search_function)


def _ibmgraphical_search_function(encoding):
    if encodings.normalize_encoding(encoding) == encodings.normalize_encoding(_IbmGraphicalCodecInfo.name):
        return _IbmGraphicalCodecInfo
    return None

codecs.register(_ibmgraphical_search_function)


class _Cp437Codec(codecs.Codec):
    # https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.12.1/Lib/encodings/cp437.py#L9
    def encode(self,input,errors='strict'):
        return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,_cp437_encoding_map)
    def decode(self,input,errors='strict'):
        return codecs.charmap_decode(input,errors,_cp437_decoding_map)

class _Cp437IncrementalEncoder(codecs.IncrementalEncoder):
    def encode(self, input, final=False):
        return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,_cp437_encoding_map)[0]

class _Cp437IncrementalDecoder(codecs.IncrementalDecoder):
    def decode(self, input, final=False):
        return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,_cp437_decoding_map)[0]

class _Cp437StreamWriter(_Cp437Codec,codecs.StreamWriter):
    pass

class _Cp437StreamReader(_Cp437Codec,codecs.StreamReader):
    pass

_Cp437CodecInfo = codecs.CodecInfo(
    # https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.12.1/Lib/encodings/cp437.py#L34
    name='x-microsoft-437',
    encode=_Cp437Codec().encode,
    decode=_Cp437Codec().decode,
    incrementalencoder=_Cp437IncrementalEncoder,
    incrementaldecoder=_Cp437IncrementalDecoder,
    streamreader=_Cp437StreamReader,
    streamwriter=_Cp437StreamWriter,
)


class _IbmGraphicalCodec(codecs.Codec):
    # https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.12.1/Lib/encodings/cp437.py#L9
    def encode(self,input,errors='strict'):
        return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,_ibmgraphical_encoding_map)
    def decode(self,input,errors='strict'):
        return codecs.charmap_decode(input,errors,_ibmgraphical_decoding_map)

class _IbmGraphicalIncrementalEncoder(codecs.IncrementalEncoder):
    def encode(self, input, final=False):
        return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,_ibmgraphical_encoding_map)[0]

class _IbmGraphicalIncrementalDecoder(codecs.IncrementalDecoder):
    def decode(self, input, final=False):
        return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,_ibmgraphical_decoding_map)[0]

class _IbmGraphicalStreamWriter(_IbmGraphicalCodec,codecs.StreamWriter):
    pass

class _IbmGraphicalStreamReader(_IbmGraphicalCodec,codecs.StreamReader):
    pass

_IbmGraphicalCodecInfo = codecs.CodecInfo(
    name='x-ibm-graphical',
    encode=_IbmGraphicalCodec().encode,
    decode=_IbmGraphicalCodec().decode,
    incrementalencoder=_IbmGraphicalIncrementalEncoder,
    incrementaldecoder=_IbmGraphicalIncrementalDecoder,
    streamreader=_IbmGraphicalStreamReader,
    streamwriter=_IbmGraphicalStreamWriter,
)


_cp437_decoding_map = _psf_cp437.decoding_map | {
  0x01: 0x263a,
  0x02: 0x263b,
  0x03: 0x2665,
  0x04: 0x2666,
  0x05: 0x2663,
  0x06: 0x2660,
  0x0b: 0x2642,
  0x0c: 0x2640,
  0x0e: 0x266b,
  0x0f: 0x263c,
  0x10: 0x25ba,
  0x11: 0x25c4,
  0x12: 0x2195,
  0x13: 0x203c,
  0x14: 0x00b6,
  0x15: 0x00a7,
  0x16: 0x25ac,
  0x17: 0x21a8,
  0x18: 0x2191,
  0x19: 0x2193,
  0x1a: 0x2192,
  0x1b: 0x2190,
  0x1c: 0x221f,
  0x1d: 0x2194,
  0x1e: 0x25b2,
  0x1f: 0x25bc,
  0x7f: 0x2302
}

_cp437_encoding_map = {n: i for (i, n) in _cp437_decoding_map.items()}


_ibmgraphical_decoding_map = _psf_cp437.decoding_map | {
  0x01: 0x263a,
  0x02: 0x263b,
  0x03: 0x2665,
  0x04: 0x2666,
  0x05: 0x2663,
  0x06: 0x2660,
  0x07: 0x2022,
  0x08: 0x25d8,
  0x09: 0x25cb,
  0x0a: 0x25d9,
  0x0b: 0x2642,
  0x0c: 0x2640,
  0x0d: 0x266a,
  0x0e: 0x266b,
  0x0f: 0x263c,
  0x10: 0x25ba,
  0x11: 0x25c4,
  0x12: 0x2195,
  0x13: 0x203c,
  0x14: 0x00b6,
  0x15: 0x00a7,
  0x16: 0x25ac,
  0x17: 0x21a8,
  0x18: 0x2191,
  0x19: 0x2193,
  0x1a: 0x2192,
  0x1b: 0x2190,
  0x1c: 0x221f,
  0x1d: 0x2194,
  0x1e: 0x25b2,
  0x1f: 0x25bc,
  0x7f: 0x2302
}

_ibmgraphical_encoding_map = {n: i for (i, n) in _ibmgraphical_decoding_map.items()}


# Permit escape to be "encoded", to avoid breaking colorama ~= 0.4.6
_ibmgraphical_encoding_map[0x001b] = _cp437_encoding_map[0x001b] = _cp437_encoding_map[0x2190]
```

It implements exactly the Microsoft codepage 437, except that, to avoid breaking `colorama ~= 0.4.6`, it accepts `u'\x1b'` while encoding, mapping it to the same byte sequence as `u'\u2190'`.

It also includes the IBM memory-mapped graphics encoding — at least, implements the table Ken Whistler published for it via the Unicode Consortium in the 1990s; obviously, I have no idea whether that table is genuinely correct. (The same concession to Colorama compatibility was included in that encoding, as well.)

Comment: For completeness I would have preferred an option to get the "ambiguous characters" as glyphs instead of control characters.

Comment: @MarkRansom I'm not opposed to adding that, though I'll ask: what system have you found that uses such a codec? The *Microsoft* codepage 437 has the mixture of glyphs and control characters I've filed here as `x-microsoft-437`; I'd be happy to add another entry to this post, but I'm curious what it would be named.

Comment: I can't remember my motivation for asking the question originally, I suspect it was in the context of answering somebody else's question.  I do know that very early DOS programs could write directly to display memory to get all the characters, and a mapping would be necessary to convert them for modern use.

Comment: Maybe you could call it `x-ibm-437` since it's the IBM display adapters where the characters originated?

Comment: Or, as I said, just have the one class with a parameter to `__init__` to add the extra glyphs.

Comment: @MarkRansom I added that into the post; let me know if it gets any use!