# Deducing console codepage when PEP 528 may or may not be implemented?

Tags: python, character-encoding, future-proof

I've got some code that needs to print certain non-ASCII characters to the console, when the console might not be in UTF-8 mode.

On Linux and Mac, it's *simply* the responsibility of anyone rowdy enough to use a non UTF-8 terminal to set `LANG` [and `LC_CTYPE`](https://drj11.wordpress.com/2007/05/14/python-how-is-sysstdoutencoding-chosen/#:%7E:text=BUT%20WHERE%20THE%20HELL%20IS%20THIS%20DOCUMENTED%3F)* appropriately. And on Windows with CPython ≥3.6, the PSF handles this with [PEP 528](https://peps.python.org/pep-0528/).

*If you're reading this in the future (on CPython ≥3.15) it looks like [that'll be `PYTHONIOENCODING`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0686/).

However, that still leaves un-handled the case of people using something like PyPy on Windows. In that case, Python starts up naïvely with `sys.stdout.encoding == 'utf-8'`, **regardless** of the actual codepage the terminal is using (and there's no "rowdy user", Homebrew maintainer, or Linux distribution administrator to be held responsible for not setting good env vars in this case.).

I'm currently working around it by just setting `sys.stdout.encoding` to whatever `chcp` says whenever "PyPy on Windows" is detected, but this will fail when PyPy implements PEP 528:

```py
import platform
import re
import subprocess
import sys

#import colorama

def fixit():
    # implementation note: MUST be run before the first read from stdin.
    # (stdout and sterr may be already written-to, albeit maybe corruptedly.)
    if platform.system() == 'Windows':
        #colorama.just_fix_windows_console()
        if platform.python_implementation() == 'PyPy':
            if sys.pypy_version_info > (7, 3, 15):
                import warnings
                warnings.warn("Applying workaround for https://github.com/pypy/pypy/issues/2999")
            chcp_output = subprocess.check_output(['chcp.com'], encoding='ascii')
            cur_codepage = int(re.match(r'Active code page: (\d+)', chcp_output).group(1))
            cur_encoding = WINDOWS_CODEPAGES[cur_codepage]
            for f in [sys.stdin, sys.stdout, sys.stderr]:
                if f.encoding != cur_encoding
                    f.reconfigure(encoding=cur_encoding)


WINDOWS_CODEPAGES = {
  437: 'ibm437',
  850: 'ibm850',
  1252: 'windows-1252',
  28591: 'iso-8859-1',
  28592: 'iso-8859-2',
  28593: 'iso-8859-3',
  65000: 'utf-7',
  65001: 'utf-8'
}
```

Now, it seems to me to me that calling `sys.stdout.reconfigure(encoding=sys.stdout._TTY_CODEPAGE)` whenever `sys.stdout.encoding != sys.stdout._TTY_CODEPAGE` is a **very sane and correct thing to do**.

But that leaves me with the question: just exactly *how* can I get `sys.stdout._TTY_CODEPAGE` on Windows, when PEP 528 might-or-might-not be implemented?

Comment: PEPs fundamentally don't work like that. I would advise you to start by reading PEP 1 in order to understand what PEPs actually are.

Comment: "how can I check for "the changes that were implemented in PEP 528"" - that's my point: PEPs **don't** "implement changes". Rather, the reference implementation of CPython implements changes, and the PEP process is used to **discuss and document** those changes. There are no discoverable "flags" or anything that can tell you which PEPs are implemented, because PEPs *don't correspond to features or change-sets* in that way.

Comment: A large fraction of PEPs *don't have anything to do with the Python implementation at all!* They include concerns like style guides for the developers, high-level design considerations for Python 3 when that was being planned out; governance process for the Python Software Foundation, conventions used by the packaging system; documentation of various standards; etc. etc. There are even some jokes and Easter eggs. What you are asking for doesn't make sense to ask for, because it fundamentally depends on PEPs being something that they just are not.

Comment: If you want to know how to detect whether the Python implementation supports *a UTF-8 console*, the issue here is that the `io._WindowsConsoleIO` class mentioned in the PyPy issue report is **not part of the interface** for Python; it's a CPython implementation detail. The Python dev team decides how CPython works, and it's up to everyone else to emulate it. The question of "what version of FooPython does the same thing as CPython X.Y?" can only be answered by the FooPython devs, and there isn't necessarily a 1:1 correspondence.

Comment: "Does it actually "not make sense to ask for" a check for PEP 528 support" - it indeed does not, because there is nothing built in to the system that makes for any kind of explicit checklist of "implemented PEPs", not in general and not for any particular PEP. The closest thing you get is the `__future__` module, but that only covers a very small set of features - the ones that were designed as opt-in from an earlier CPython version than the one where they became standard. But also because there is no standardization of other implementations or how they correspond to CPython.

Comment: I think you are stuck doing what you are doing, unfortunately. FWIW, it doesn't look unreasonable to me. Would pass my code review.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel You're right, actually. Technically what I don't care about is "PEP 528"; the actual thing I care about is finding the TTY codepage for *sys.stdout.buffer*, which PEP 528 happens to force to become UTF-8 \(Verify it with this command: `chcp 437 & py -c "import subprocess, sys; print('In Python:', subprocess.check_output(['chcp.com'], encoding='ascii').strip()); sys.stdout.buffer.write('Despite the preceeding, sys.stdout.buffer is still UTF-8: \u03C8'.encode('utf-8'))"`\)

Comment: I thought Python was already using Windows console functions directly instead of relying on byte encodings?  The intent being that your program uses Unicode exclusively and the console I/O "just works".  Not sure what PEP 528 changes.

Comment: @MarkRansom Older versions of Python had all kinds of problems with Unicode output on Windows. You should count yourself lucky if you never had to experience it yourself. PEP 528 describes the changes introduced in CPython 3.6 to fix the problem - I wouldn't be surprised if it indeed "uses Windows console functions directly" to make it work, via an internal wrapper class. But other implementations may or may not fix the corresponding problem at any particular version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(As the OP stated, Mac and Linux *already* expose that information via environment variables, so I'm only providing the Windows solution here.)*

When Python is *not* overriding your standard input and output with synthetic I/O classes*, the appropriate calls are `ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetConsoleCP()` for input and `ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetConsoleOutputCP()` for output. These will return a [Microsoft "code page identifier"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/code-page-identifiers), which must be crudely and awkwardly mapped to a Python "encoding".

However, neither the PSF nor any alternate implementation includes this mapping by default. There are various community-contributed mappings floating around online, but it's not clear if any of them are correct.

All of these mappings will be incomplete, anyway, as Python's included "[cp437](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.12.2/Lib/encodings/cp437.py)" and "[oem](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.12.2/Modules/_codecsmodule.c#L934)" encodings **disagree** with the actual behavior of Windows CMD on its default codepage 437 on all of `{u'\u00a7', u'\u00b6', u'\u203c', u'\u2190', u'\u2191', u'\u2192', u'\u2193', u'\u2195', u'\u21a8', u'\u221f', u'\u2302', u'\u25ac', u'\u25b2', u'\u25ba', u'\u25bc', u'\u25c4', u'\u263a', u'\u263b', u'\u263c', u'\u2640', u'\u2642', u'\u2660', u'\u2663', u'\u2665', u'\u2666', u'\u266b'}`. (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77943303/1874170) for more details, and an "x-microsoft-cp437" codec that bridges the gap.)

---

*The best *known* way to check if Python is overriding a console file with a synthetic class is:

```py
import io
import sys
import warnings

def is_synthetic_tty(f=sys.stdout):
    """Returns True if *f* is a synthetic TTY such as PEP 528; returns False otherwise."""

    if not f.isatty():
        return False

    if sys.platform.implementation() == 'CPython':
        return not isinstance(f.raw, io.FileIO)

    elif sys.platform.implementation() == 'PyPy':
        if sys.pypy_version_info > (7, 3, 15):
            warnings.warn("https://github.com/pypy/pypy/issues/2999")
        return not isinstance(f.raw, io.FileIO)

    else:
        warnings.warn(f"Unrecognized implementation, {sys.platform.implementation()!r}")
        return not isinstance(f.raw, io.FileIO)
```

When this occurs, the console codepage is [likely UTF-16LE hiding behind a hard-coded UTF-8 wrapper](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.12.2/Modules/_io/winconsoleio.c#L1018) which does not respect `.encoding` and `.reconfigure()`, which means you have **no hope** of identifying it and should not interact with its encoding at all, instead only writing [Unicode Strings](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#the-string-type) into it.

A core PyPy maintainer has ambiguously suggested both that he [might](https://github.com/pypy/pypy/issues/2999#issuecomment-1929076618) and that he [might not](https://github.com/pypy/pypy/issues/2999#issuecomment-1915484177) implement a solution that's even compatible with this check, so keeping that warning is is absolutely critical. There is **not** currently a future-proof solution to detect this situation.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if there's any way to detect it via the properties Python exhibits.  But you can simply query to see if it's a version that is known to implement the PEP.

```
def has_pep528():
    try:
        import platform
        import sys
        if platform.python_implementation() == 'CPython' and tuple(sys.version_info) >= (3, 6):
            return True
    except:
        pass
    return False
```

You can add additional `if` statements as other implementations become known.

Comment: CPython versions `< (3, 6)` are no longer supported; I don't need to handle them. And I don't know what exact version PyPy will implement PEP 528 or similar behavior.